# Cannot Access DeletedItems through Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to access the [DeletedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) via Microsoft Graph.

Here is my code:

```
graphClient
  .Directory
  .DeletedItems[userid]
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

I receive this exception response:

```
Code: BadRequest. 
Message: Resource not found for the segment 'directory'.
```

Anyone knows how to access `deletedItems` correctly? Am I missing something to access it?

Comment: Are you able to list the `deletedItems` (`/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user`)?

Comment: Yes, I can list the deletedItems by visiting https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user. But don't know how to do it by code. It seems there are no such method supported currently.

Answer (score 4):

This particular call is a little unusual in that the Id that is used is not actually the user Id, but is object type or objectId.  So to get a list of deleted items, you pass the type in the array index.

e.g.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(null);

var request = graphClient
      .Directory
      .DeletedItems["microsoft.graph.user"]
      .Request()
      .GetHttpRequestMessage();

var content = new HttpMessageContent(request);
Console.Write(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.Read();


Output:

GET /v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.13.0
```

The above code demonstrates a handy way of seeing exactly what HTTP request the library is attempting to send.  It requires pulling in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` Nuget to get the `HttpMessageContent` object.